# Setting up a Huawei LTE stick e3372 on a raspberry

Tags: networking, iptables, modem

I have just taken over a project from a colleague so I am not 100% sure what this pi have been up to before.

Anyways, my task is to setup a Huawei LTE usb Stick (E3372) as a modem for the raspberry so that we can have internet access anywhere. I have tried to follow a few guide but still can't seem to get any internet connection. My best clue so far has been that there was something wrong with the routing but by chance I just tried to connect the usb stick to my pc and realized that I had two profiles to choose between: 3G or 4G and only 4g seems to give me a functional internet connection. So maybe the routing itself is not m problem but rather the profile.

So my question is: how do I do change this in Raspian (preferably from the console) and do i need to do this?

In many of the guides they refer to different dial up programs but I have jst assumed that i do not need that for this modem. Maybe i am wrong?

> ifconfig gives:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:c5:70:20
          inet addr:169.254.59.104  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ba27:ebff:fec5:7020/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1557 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1410 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:150129 (146.6 KiB)  TX bytes:247508 (241.7 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:919 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:919 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:74536 (72.7 KiB)  TX bytes:74536 (72.7 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:90:25:75
          inet6 addr: fe80::ba27:ebff:fe90:2575/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5480 errors:0 dropped:5480 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:25 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:2101712 (2.0 MiB)  TX bytes:4351 (4.2 KiB)

wwan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1e:10:1f:00:00
          inet addr:169.254.62.145  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::b0b4:a7ba:fee8:b03/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:62 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:15484 (15.1 KiB)
```

Trying to ping google from the wwan0 interface:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ping -I wwan0 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 169.254.62.145 wwan0: 56(84) bytes of data.
From 169.254.62.145 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

My routing table:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt     Iface
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 wwan0
```

My /etc/network/interfaces file:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wwan0
iface wwan0 inet dhcp
```

Comment: 169 network is not routable in the Internet at large. You are not getting an IP. Are you running/have you installed/configured a DHCP client?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I am not sure. But it seems like the modem is acting as a DHCP server. If I connect my PC to the raspberry through eth0 my pc is also given a 169.254.xxx.xxx address. How this is configured i do not know.

Comment: I was not clear. 169.x.x.x is a special automatic IP address that equipment assume when they cannot get a DHCP given address.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Aha, I will have a look. Thx

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I have the default dhclient using the default dhclient.conf. However I am not sure what I would need to change if anything.

Comment: Please add /etc/network/interfaces to the post. Those USB sticks are a little ungrateful to work as they can be reprogrammed in two or three different modes of operation; in the default mode they are no more than glorified USB memory sticks if memory does not fail me. I managed to reprogram one to send SMS alerts for our Nagios, it was a royal pain in the ass to find the correct steps how to do that.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro i have added the interface file. I have done some changes to it but I do not know enough about networks to see if that is the reason for my problems.

Comment: I added two lines by mistake to the question instead of the answer and do not have enough reputation to delete them...

Comment: interfaces seem ok, and the ifconfig too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38902/discussion-between-jimmy-and-rui-f-ribeiro).